# Moving / directory in linux

Tags: ubuntu, partition, root-filesystem

I installed ubuntu with dual boot alongside Windows 8. While partitioning I allocated 9.8 GB to the root directory of linux.Now i am short on space with only 700MB space remaining in this root directory. I cannot delete this OS because i have important application and files which run only on the Linux environment. Is there any way i can shift the root directory to another partition(I have an empty 17GB partition /dev/sda12 ) or increase the partition size?

This is how my partitions look like-

[image]

The error messgae when i boot into Windows is:

```
File : \Boot\BCD
Status : 0xc000000e
Info : The boot configuration Data on your PC is missing or contains errors
```

Comment: This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87579/discussion-on-question-by-nobody-moving-directory-in-linux).

Answer (score 1):

Let's follow these steps:

**BACKUP ALL IMPORTED FILES**

=========================================

#### Overall Process

1. Backup you Ubuntu system
2. Identify UUID of new partition
3. Modify /etc/fstab to mount new partition
4. Copy old root (`/`) to new location /media/new_root
5. Confirm copy worked
6. Switch root mount point in /etc/fstab
7. Remount all entries in the /etc/fstab
8. Delete the /media/new_root

==========================================

1. Identify the UUID of the new partition to use with the command

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```
2. Setup /etc/fstab

   1. `sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`
   2. `cmp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.$(date +%Y-%m-%d)`

      Compares the two version
   3. Edit the old `/etc/fstab`, `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

      ```
      # (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
      UUID=????????   /media/new_root    ext          defaults       0       2
      ```

      Replace `UUID` with the value for `/dev/sda12` seen in step`1` above
3. Create that mount point

   ```
   sudo mkdir /media/new_root
   ```
4. Mount `/dev/sda12`on `/media/new_root`

   ```
   sudo mount -a
   ```

   1. Copy over `/`

      ```
      sudo rsync -aXS --progress --exclude='/*/.gvfs' /. /media/new_root/.
      ```
   2. Check the copying worked

      ```
      sudo diff -r / /media/new_root -x ".gvfs/*"
      ```
5. Perform final switch

   1. `sudo nano /etc/fstab`

      ```
      # (identifier)  (location, eg sda5)   (format, eg ext3 or ext4)      (some settings) 
      UUID=????????   /    ext4          defaults       0       2
      ```

      - **IMPORTANT**: Add a `#` in front of the former entry in the `/etc/fstab` that was for the root mount i.e. `/dev/sda10`, please check and make sure you identify it using the `UUID` value.
6. Now remount to see if all  went well

   1. `sudo mount -a`
   2. Troubleshoot:

      1. *The volume may already be mounted*:

         ```
         sudo umount /media/new_root
         sudo mount -a
         ```
7. Delete `/media/new_root` if all goes well.

   ```
   sudo rm -rI /media/new_root
   ```

#### Goodluck

Source:(modified)

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

Comment: Ok sorry for being late.First of all thanks.But i have some questions
1.I am mounting the /media/new_root at partition but when i am copying / to /media/new_root wont it go in a end less loop.Like it copies all the contents until it reaches /media, there when it tries to copy /new_root to the partition it is essentially recopying it self.
Sorry if i am wrong im not very sound in linux filesystems, I just switched from windows so it is kind of new.

Comment: So i ran out of space in that partition, and can I format that again, since i changed fstab to mount sda10 as /.